# Values of θ for which r is minimized in a circle?

Tags: calculus

So, I've been stuck trying to figure out how to find the value(s) of θ where r is minimized in a circle?

The circle's equation is r = 6 sin θ with an interval of 0≤θ≤2π.

I believe the answer to be 3π/2, since I graphed out the equation, and the r value there equals -6, which is r's lowest amount in the given interval. However, I'm not very confident in my answer, and wanted to know if there is a proper way to obtain the minimum of a circle outside of graphing.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: $-6$ as sin takes the minimum at $3/2\pi$

Comment: min: sin theta = -1, theta = arcsin -1 = ...

Answer (score 1):

You know that the trigonometric functions satisfy

$-1\leq sin(\theta)\leq 1$ and

$-1\leq cos(\theta)\leq 1$

In particular $sin(\theta)=-1$ if $\theta= \frac{3}{2}\pi$

Then the minimum Value of $\sin(\theta)$ is $-1$ that means that the minimum value of $6\sin(\theta)$ is $-6$ when $\theta=\frac{3}{2}\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a proper way of doing that : in general, you compute the derivative of $r$ and see if $r$ has a minimum by studying the sign of $r'$. Assuming you know the variations of $x \mapsto \sin(x)$, here you can just say that this function reaches its minimum at $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.